# InvalidArgumentError : assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.100000: ] [1.15277779]

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am doing object detection in tensorflow and using the `faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28 model` for training locally but I am getting the follwing error:

```
    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.100000: ] [1.15277779]
    [[Node: ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1)]]
```

The traceback is :

```
    /venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py, line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I tried training using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets` but training was successful.
My training images are a mixture of different sizes. I don't believe any of my bounding boxes are outside the image coordinates. Even if that's the case why would the ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets model work but not the resnet model?

Comment: I checked my training file (.csv format) and none of the box values exceed the image dimensions.

Comment: Providing a full stack trace will make it easier for folks to answer this question.